# ES Lint error for jQuery anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, lint, eslint

The code I have is as follows:

```
$('.panel').each( function() {
    $(this).css('height', 'auto');
    $(this).find('.portlet-panel-item').css('height', 'auto');
});
```

I am getting the following error: `37:26  warning  Missing function expression name  func-names`.

I can't use the ES6 arrow functions because of the way `this` is being handled in the two use cases.

How can I fix this issue without having to put named functions for each?

Comment: You can't. You could just disable that check on that line. `// eslint-disable-next-line func-name` before it should do the trick. It's a linter, doesn't mean your code won't run or will cause errors, just that, if you agree with this rule, it's bad practice.

Comment: Maybe you should [read what the rule means first](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-names), then use your judgement as to whether the rule makes sense in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should either use a named function or disable the rule.

From [AirBnB JavaScript style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#functions):

> Don’t forget to name the expression - anonymous functions can make it harder to locate the problem in an Error's call stack.

You can [set this rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-names) to check "always", "as-needed", or "never" by using a comment, so in your case:
`/*eslint func-names: ["error", "never"]*/`